# Widevine licenses location

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, mpeg-dash, widevine

Silverlight save PlayReady licenses in the PlayReady folder.
Is there a folder where browsers (chrome-firefox) store widevine licenses for protected MPEG-DASH streams ?

Answer (score 0):

Widevine has the concept of a secure key-box to store the keys.

There are different levels of widevine (level 1, level2 and level3) which have varying requirements for his secure the device boot loading is and how the device root key is set up, but all levels will have the content license keys encrypted 'in' this key-box.

So there is not any folder which will have the license keys available in it to browse or read, if this is what you were asking.

Comment: Play ready stores licenses in the Playready folder  , if you have for example a license for some streams, you can save the folder . and if you format your PC you can recover your license by copying the folder you saved. I'm wondering if we can do the same for widevine licenses,